# Equality of Sets in Sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

Suppose I have 2 queries A and B.

Query A returns a column of values.
Query B also returns a column of values

How can I check that that the set of values that is returned from query A is equal to the set of values returned from query B?

I've tried:

[query A](select ... from ...) intersect [query B](select.. from ..) = [query B](select.. from ..),

plus the other way around. But I get

> error: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression.

I'm assuming this is because I'm not allowed to check if 2 columns are equal, I can only check atomic values?

Comment: Can you include the actual queries?

Comment: This was more of a general question. I just wanted to know in general if i have any 2 queries how could I check that their output matches

Comment: Do you have a common column that links the two tables together?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name does that make a difference? I was asking in general, so I dont think it matters? Im just saying assume you have 2 working queries that each return a set of values. How would you compare those 2 sets. Anyways the question is resolved. And regardless thankyou to everyone that took the time to look into it :) Also whoever downvoted the post would love to know why you downvoted it? I've got no problem with being downvoted as long as I know why xd

Comment: if you have a common column, you could do something like this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=53c01b3f788f33a26c3d8ac811e9493e

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are not very many values, you can use arrays:

```
select (ar_a = ar_b)
from (select string_agg(val order by val) as ar_a from a) cross join
     (select string_agg(val order by val) as ar_b from b);
```

A more SQLish way is a full join:

```
select (count(*) = count(a.val) and count(a.val) = count(b.val))
from a full join
     b
     on a.val = b.val;
```

Note:  This assumes that the values are distinct.

Comment: thanks for that. But was I correct in that I cannot just use the equals operator to check if 2 columns are equal, and that I can only do so with atomic values?

Comment: Yes you are right, but you could have done it . A bit of a weird one though and I think this is what Gordon Linoff was getting at. If you concatenate the values into one string, you can easily compare the two as long as the select order is the same.

Comment: @JohnnyDropTables: concatenating is not a good idea. But you can do `(a.col_1, a.col_2, a.col_3) is distinct from (b.col_1, b.col_2, b.col_3)`